# How do I implement a Punch Autoprefixer Pre-Processor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, static-site

I'd like to implement an [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) pre-processor for the [Punch](https://github.com/laktek/punch) static site generator.

However, in Punch parlance, I'm not sure if this would qualify as a compiler, minifier, etc. I've tried all of the above to no avail.

Here's my most recent attempt at getting *anything* working:

`./autoprefixer.js`

```
module.exports = {
    input_extensions: [".css"],
    force_compile: true,
    compile: function(input, filename, callback){
        return callback(null, "*{color: red;}");
    }
};
```

---

`config.json`

```
...
    "plugins": {
        "compilers": {
            ".css": "punch-sass-compiler",
            ".css": "autoprefixer"
        }
    }
...
```

---

`result`

```
/home/peter/projects/website/node_modules/punch/lib/asset_bundler.js:62
                        if (compiler && compiler.input_extensions.indexOf(template_extension) > -1)
                                                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
  at /home/peter/projects/website/node_modules/punch/lib/asset_bundler.js:62:45
  at /home/peter/projects/website/node_modules/punch/lib/template_handler.js:119:11
  at fs.js:334:14
  at /home/peter/projects/website/node_modules/punch/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at the moment, punch compilers can only compile from a different extension (say `.mycss` or `.less`). Using that, you're almost there:

In `module.exports`, `input_extensions:` must be set to the extension you desire (not `.css`), e.g. `[".mycss"]`.

```
"plugins": {
    "compilers": {
        ".css": "punch-sass-compiler",
        ".css": "autoprefixer"
    }
}
```

is really strange, since you're defining the same key twice. Delete the `punch-sass-compiler` line. If you want to invoke another compiler, simply `require` its module in your compiler's code, call the other compiler and modify the supplied output to your liking.

Punch minifiers are not suitable for your goal, since they only get involved in production (with `punch g`), not when developing.

Comment: Thanks! This information is all very useful. (I can't believe I'd been overlooking that duplicated key... :!) I'll take a look myself, but do you know if it'd be feasible to add support for common extensions? The existing behavior is unexpected. If it isn't too much work, I might consider submitting a patch. Though, it looks like the upstream project may have been abandoned.

Comment: @pdoherty926 The output extension must be different from the output, nothing more. If your input files are sass anyways, why not name them `.scss`?